# Ubuntu - TinyISP is not recognized

Tags: arduino-ide, linux, isp, programmer, ubuntu

I got a Pocket AVR Programmer.

https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/pocket-avr-programmer-hookup-guide

I hooked it up on Ubuntu Linux, opened up a sketch in the Arduino IDE, selected `Programmer: USBTinyISP` and then `Upload Using Programmer`.

However, I am getting this error:

```
An error occured while uploading the sketch
avrdude: Warning: cannot open USB device: Permission denied
avrdude: Error: Could not find USBtiny device (0x1781/0xc9f)
```

I even followed this blog post:
https://www.krekr.nl/content/using-usbtinyisp-with-ubuntu/
and issued these commands:

In a terminal, type:

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-USBtiny
```

Then paste

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1781", ATTR{idProduct}=="0c9f", GROUP="adm", MODE="0666"
```

into the new file. Write it out by pressing Ctrl-O.

```
sudo usermod -a -G plugdev YOURUSERNAME
sudo service udev restart
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

However, the problem still remains.

Comment: Use lsusb or dmesg to confirm that the device is listed.

Comment: please do not post picture of text ... copy and paste the text into your question instead ... format as code

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the libusb?

> sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev

Comment: I'm not sure this actually answers the question that was asked.

Comment: Why not? usbtiny needs the libusb driver installed to properly work, if it's now installed it won't work, at least in UBUNTU

Comment: Thanks but libusb was already installed....